# How to extend VueConfiguration? I.e. how to extend existing interface?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, interface, vuejs2

Seems like an easy task but I get confused.

Let's say I want to add `server` object to `Vue.config`.
Here is typescript definition for Vue - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/vue.d.ts#L121. So we need to extend VueConfiguration interface - https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/vue.d.ts#L67

I tried to create index.d.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/vue/types/vue.d.ts" />

export interface VueConfiguration {
    server: {
        user: string;
    }
}
```

in `src/` directory, that does not help.

Tried to add this code into main.ts file:

```
declare interface VueConfiguration {
  server: {
      blockchain: string;
  };
};
```

When I do:

```
Vue.config.server.user = 'http://127.0.0.1:8082'
```

I got error Property 'server' does not exist on type 'VueConfiguration'

So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to modify an existing interface. Rather, you should create a new interface that extends the old interface and then use a type assertion on your object to let the TS compiler know about these additional properties.

```
export interface MyVueConfiguration extends VueConfiguration {
    server: {
        user: string;
    }
}

...

(Vue.config as MyVueConfiguration).server.user = 'http://127.0.0.1:8082'
```

Comment: thank you.
that's one way but with my own interface I need to manually patch `new Vue({})` request since they will use VueConfiguration anyway. Seems like vue is not really ready for typescirpt.